# how to click a button if color matches

Tags: python, selenium, automation, pyautogui

i need to click a button if it's color is "139, 140, 199" and i have tried pyautogui and never worked, can i do that with selnium????

```
    def mute_cam(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        cam_xpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/calling-pre-join-screen/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/section/div[2]/toggle-button[1]/div/button/span[1]'
        self.rgb = driver.find_element_by_xpath(cam_xpath).value_of_css_property('background')
        list = [self.rgb]
        str_list = str(self.rgb)
        new_list = str_list[4:17]
        print(new_list)
```

i have tried to store the color in a list and then compare it, but the thing is i have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can get any CSS property of an element in Selenium via Javascript or by using `.value_of_css_property`

Below is an example of fetching a list of buttons as found on the Bootstrap documentation [page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/) and getting their `background-color`.

```py
driver.get("https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/")

btn_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'bd-example'][1]/button")

for itm in range(0, len(btn_list)):
    name = btn_list[itm].text
    print(name)
    color = btn_list[itm].value_of_css_property("backgroundColor")
    print(color)

    if color == "rgba(0, 123, 255, 1)":
    # do any action    
    print("Button with Primary color detected")
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Primary
rgba(0, 123, 255, 1)
Button with Primary color detected
Secondary
rgba(108, 117, 125, 1)
Success
rgba(40, 167, 69, 1)
Danger
rgba(220, 53, 69, 1)
Warning
rgba(255, 193, 7, 1)
Info
rgba(23, 162, 184, 1)
Light
rgba(248, 249, 250, 1)
Dark
rgba(52, 58, 64, 1)
Link
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: i already have the RGB, but i need to click the button if the button is the same color as my variable

Comment: You can do something like ```if element.value_of_css_property("backgroundColor") == ABC: element.click()```

Comment: Kindly accept this solution as an answer if it was useful.

Comment: self.rgb = driver.find_element_by_xpath(cam_xpath)
        if self.rgb.value_of_css_property("background") == (139, 140, 199): 
            self.rgb.click()

Comment: It should be ```.value_of_css_property("backgroundColor")``` instead of ```.value_of_css_property("background")```. Try to run my version of code on your system and see if that works. Comment here if you face any problem.

Comment: Also the color ```(139, 140, 199)``` you are trying to compare should be a ```string```. First try to print out the fetched color value using selenium, and check if that is executing as intended.